# In SWT how can I bring one button infront of another

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, eclipse-rcp

How can I bring "NewButton"  in front of "Button" in SWT? Please refer to the below image: In other words, how to send "Button" to the back of "NewButton"?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setBounds(10,10,300,300);
    Button b =new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
    b.setText("Button");
    b.setBounds(60,60,80,80);
    Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText("NewButton");

    button.setBounds(120,120,90,90);
    button.moveAbove(b); shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
    if (!display.readAndDispatch()) display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
    }
```